# Drum sander attachment for drill keeps coming loose

Tags: drill, sanding, sander

[image]

Like in the picture. It's doing a great job (floorboards and skirting boards) but it keeps working itself out of the drill - I can see it creeping out gradually, and after about a minute of use it falls off. I've got the chuck as tight as I can get it.

It's actually worn away the spindle bit that goes in the drill, too, presumably it is constantly slipping inside the drill.

I'm using a very heavy duty sandpaper grade on it - 40 grit - for the first pass to take all the crap off. Could that be part of the problem?

Greatful for any advice.... cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your Drill Chuck is actually the problem here.

You can try a few different things.

- Buy a new chuck for that drill.
- Buy a new high quality drill.
- Since your spindle is damaged already, you might want to put a groove in it for your chuck to bite into it.

I have no relation or affiliation with any of the following - I am supplying the links so you can see some different ways to get new chucks.

In No particular order of quality, usefulness or reputation; Links for Replacement Chucks Follow:

[Toolots](http://www.toolots.com/machine-tool-industry/machine-tool-accessories/machine-tool-accessories-drill-chucks-arbors.html?mode=grid&gclid=CMD-pIDBgtQCFdgvgQoddgINEw)

[Jacobs Chucks](http://www.jacobschuck.com/)

[At Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Drill-Chucks/b?ie=UTF8&node=8106518011)

[Craftsman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BCNFMI4)

Comment: One additional thought.  Use less pressure when sanding.  That's a big diameter drum and the sandpaper has a lot of friction.  High sanding pressure involves some heavy forces on the spindle.

Comment: Thanks ken. The drill is old and the chuck is quite stiff. I'd been thinking about getting an SDS drill for extra power and a non slip bit but haven't been able to work it into our limited household budget!

Comment: @fixer1234 I think there is too much torque like you say, I tried it with my battery drill/screwdriver, which has an auto cutoff and it kept stopping. I'll try it with a lighter grit and less pressure and more patience! Cheers

Comment: It never occurred to me that the chuck could be replaced though - I'll look into that, thanks

Comment: @ken What sort of groove did you mean, for the spindle?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, bits like spade bits, which need a lot more torque than a regular drill bit, often don't have a round spindle.  They have flatted sides for the chuck jaws to grab.  That would be easy to replicate, and is likely to be enough.  Try that before replacing the chuck.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Fitting a groove where your chuck tooth can get stuck against - enough to give it a grip - right now all it is doing is slipping.Torque does factor in but note your are using a tool designed for a drill , your drill chuck should be able to handle it. I will try to post a link for chucks..

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 but how would I attach the spade bit to the drum sander (or vice versa)?

Comment: BTW the battery-powered drill/screwdriver has been doing a great job, not coming loose at all, though it churns through the battery like nobody's business.  So i think the problem is with my old drill.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, what I meant was to grind some flats into the drum's spindle in the same style.